# i want to copy paste only numbers from one sheet to another

Tags: vba

i am trying to copy and paste only numbers/values from one sheet to another. The code i am working with copy all type values. will appreciate if someone can modify my code

```
          Set wb = ThisWorkbook
          Set src = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
          Set tgt = wb.Sheets("sheet2")

              With src

           Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           With .Range("A8:A" & Lastrow)

             tgt.Range("A8").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value2


              End With
End With
```

Comment: You want to copy everything on Sht to tgt which is number ?

Comment: so i am copying the values from A8 to lastrow(sheet1) and pasting it to sheet2 A8~. However its also copying string values and i just want to copy number or integer values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the below code:**

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("sheet2")

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 8 To lastrow

        If IsNumeric(src.Range("A" & i).Value) Then

            tgt.Range("A" & i).Value = src.Range("A" & i).Value

        End If

   Next
```

Will only copy values in column A. You can amend it for other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

If keeping the same pasting location isn't important, using the .`union` could be an efficient way for bigger sets of data.

What it does is, it takes all the values that are *numeric* and then pastes them all after it's done with the *loop*.

Problem with this approach might be that it just pastes the *numeric* values one after another, whatever their location was in **Sheet1**.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim combine As Range
              Set src = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
              Set tgt = wb.Sheets("sheet2")

                  With src

                Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

               For i = 8 To Lastrow
               If IsNumeric(Range("A" & i)) Then
                If combine Is Nothing Then
                Set combine = Range("A" & i)
            Else
                Set combine = Union(combine, Range("A" & i))
                End If
            End If
            Next i

               End With

      combine.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A8")
```